# Nesting SQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

Nesting SQL queries in PHP seems to be a bit of a worry.
I needed a SQL query to populate select options in a drupal form and I used the following query.

```
SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 1124 and cid = 4 and 
data not in (SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data where nid = 1127 and cid = 11 group by data having COUNT(*) > 5)
```

This query work perfectly fine in phpMyAdmin, but when i try it out in a PHP code (given below) using db_query, it doesn't work (nothing is returned).

```
$array = array();
$sql = db_query("SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 1124 and cid = 4 and data not in (SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data where nid = 1127 and cid = 11 group by data having COUNT(*) > 5)");
while($row = db_fetch_object($sql)) {
$array[$row->data] = $row->data;
}
return $array;
```

Could anyone please correct me wrt what is wrong in my query or code ?
Also, is there a way to implement this query in PHP ?

Comment: db_query shouldn't be mysql_query ? Saying that because you tagged MySQL...

Comment: Can you provide more details about what doesn't work? do you get an error message?

Comment: What's "not work". You get an error? Odd/wrong/no results?

Comment: The above query is used to populate a dynamic checkbox in a drupal webform. If I use this query in my PHP code it does not populate the checkbox. Any ideas/suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it worth point out that the two queries are not the same?

The first query, from phpMyAdmin, uses a `AND NOT EXISTS (...subquery...)`.

The second uses `and data not in (... subquery ... )`.

Implies different behavior.

*EDIT*

In Drupal 6, the `data` field in `webform_submitted_data` is a `mediumtext` field. Using its content as a array key may not be a good idea. How about changing your query like this:

```
$array = array();
$sql = db_query("SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 1124 and cid = 4    and data not in (SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data where nid = 1127 and cid = 11   group by data having COUNT(*) > 5)");
while($row = db_fetch_object($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row->data;  // <<<<----- updated array push
}
return $array;
```

This way, you still get an array of results, but without having to use a long string value as key and possibly overwriting duplicates.

Comment: You are right. However, OP noted that the result is not quite the expected and mentioned the query ran in phpMyAdmin is OK. Therefore, OP must use what is recognizably working.

Comment: [Modified the original Post]
i am sry for the query mismatch.. Both the queries mean the same.. i was just trying out to see if any of it works good in PHP. But it didn't.

Comment: Works like charm... Thanks a tonne Ryan Bates :)

Comment: Your welcome! Please mark the question as answered if this solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Heads up, you are not using the same query! As you let us know that the first query is the one whose result you are looking for, change the PHP to the actual query you ran in phpMyAdmin:

```
$sql = db_query("SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 1124 and cid = 4 and not EXISTS (SELECT data FROM webform_submitted_data where nid = 1127 and cid = 11 group by data having COUNT(*) > 5)");
```

**Update**

You noted that both queries should work, but none is working. I assume no error is being thrown as you stated that

> (nothing is returned)

I do not see any reason for this query not to be working. Make sure you are connecting to the same database.

Comment: [Modified the original Post] i am sorry for the query mismatch.. Both the queries mean the same.. I was just trying out to see if any of it works good in PHP. But it didn't.
Both NOT EXISTS and NOT IN works good in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I was a bit confused... Adrian Bates explained the error in his reply and it now works fine.
Reason  : "data field in webform_submitted_data is a mediumtext  field. Using its content as a array key may not be a good idea. "

Comment: Great! You should accept Bates' answer then. I'm happy it solved your issue :)